# Netsuite Javascript Grab Last Array Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, netsuite

So I found some info on this site on how to go about grabbing the value of the last index of an array. I have an Array that is of an unknown length. It builds based on a search of results. For example:

```
var custid = nlapiGetFieldValue('entity');
    var custRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', custid);
    var itemPriceLineCount = custRecord.getLineItemCount('itempricing');
    for (var i = 1; i <= itemPriceLineCount; i++) {

        var priceItemId = [];
        priceItemId = custRecord.getLineItemValue('itempricing', 'item', i);
        if (priceItemId == itemId) {
            var histCol = [];
            histCol[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('entity');
            histCol[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('totalcostestimate');
            histCol[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid');
            histCol[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('trandate');
            var histFilter = [];
            histFilter[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'is', custid);
            histFilter[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('item', null, 'is', itemId);
            var histSearch = nlapiSearchRecord('invoice', null, histFilter, histCol);
            for (var h = 0; h <= histSearch.length; h++) {
                var itemRate = new Array();
                var histSearchResult = histSearch[h];
                itemRate = histSearchResult.getValue('totalcostestimate');




            }

        }

    }
```

Now when I use:

var last_element = itemRate[itemRate.length - 1];

It gives me the number of digits/placeholders in each element of the array. So as per my example I know my array holds the values of .00 and 31.24 because I put them there for a test. So last_element will result in 3 and 5. How can I grab the value 31.24 or the last element period? I need the value not the number of digits.

Comment: @user4703663 Tried that. Getting a result that I do not need

Comment: Not clear enough what is your intention. Can it be reworded so that we can help you in a better way.

Comment: @Rockstar  I tried array[array.length-1] and this gives me the count of characters/digits in each element. So I filled my array with 2 numbers. .00 and 31.24  The results will alert a '3' and a '5'. So if you count the decimal and the digits you can see that its counting that and not returning the element or value itself. I am not sure on how to make this return the last element(31.24 is the result that I want) Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var itemRate = new Array();// Not sure what you intend to do with this array
var histSearchResult = histSearch[h];
itemRate = histSearchResult.getValue('totalcostestimate'); // but note `itemRate` is no more an array here. Its a variable having the value of `totalcostestimate` in string format
```

Now coming to your use case

```
    /* you're trying to get the length of the string value and subtracting -1 from it.
       So its very obvious to get those number of digits */

        var last_element = itemRate[itemRate.length - 1]; // returns you that index value of the string
```

If you want to get the last array value of your search i.e `histSearch`

You may want to do something like this

```
var last_element = histSearch[histSearch.length-1].getValue('totalcostestimate');
```

As a side note it is always recommended to validate the returning value from a saved search result. Because on a successful search it returns you an array object on the other hand if no result founds it'll return you `null`.

```
//likely to get an error saying can't find length from null
    for (var h = 0; h <= histSearch.length; h++) {
    }
```

You can use something like this

```
// Never enter into the loop if it is null
        for (var h = 0; histSearch!=null && h <= histSearch.length; h++) {
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. I am new to coding and this helped. The for statement I always check for null just left it out by accident there. I never had to do anything with array's so far in netsuite besides building a list. The list would not populate unless I put var myArray = []; So I just assumed I needed it here as well.

Comment: This worked perfectly and it's answers like these that keep me coming back. Normally I just get bashed on how my code sucks. For beginners it's rough to ask on here lol. I could hug you!